# Show image name on text click

Tags: jquery

hello all i want to show image  name on text click without creating multiple ids for p tag element . thanks in advance.

```js
$('img').click(function()
{
 var test = $(this).attr('src').split("/").pop();
 document.getElementById("result").value= test;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div>
     <img src="1.png">
     <div>
     <p>click<p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="2.png">
     <div>
     <p>click</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="3.png">
     <div>
     <p>click</p>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the text?

Comment: on result id i want to show.

Comment: Check my answer now, i think that's what you are looking for

Comment: thanks isac but the p tag element in inside another div so .prev() will not work for this one.

Comment: What do you mean? it works fine in the snippet. Do you have other p tags in other row divs? If so add another class to this main row div, and change the selector to `$('.myNewClass p').click(....`

Comment: hello isac you didn't get me. The .prev() works  if  the image and <p> element are in the same <div>  not in different <div>.

Comment: Can you provide a sample html when they are not in the same `<div>`. Or how would you know which one does it map to, if they are not in the same `<div>`? . Edit - i see you changed your html, let me update mine too

Comment: u haven't seen it. its okay.

Comment: It is updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```js
$('.row p').click(function() {
  //simple version
  var text = $(this).parent().prev().attr('src').split("/").pop();
  
  //a more generic version would be
  //var text = $(this).parent().parent().find('img').attr('src').split("/").pop();
  
  $("#result").val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <img src="1.png">
    <div>
      <p>click</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="2.png">
    <div>
      <p>click</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="3.png">
    <div>
      <p>click</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="result">
</form>
```

Also note that your first `<p>click<p>` tag is not properly closed, and it should be `<p>click</p>`

Comment: thanks a lot isac.about that  p tag i forgot to close that one.